# tab activity not supported in android 2.1 in android application?

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i have to implement a full url in android device.I have made the application in android 3.2.Now acc to client requirement he wants the same code to be runned in android 2.1. But its crashing when i try to run the same code in android 2.1 updated 1. I have done r & d and done all the formulas suggested,i have changed the sdk version in the manifest file.Added configuration code in java file,,but still crashing.Is dere any way in which the same app can run on android 2.1 updated 1 .What i think is 2.1 updated 1 does not support tab bars.......if anyone has faced the same issue,,can he guide me

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Comment: what is exception it throws in logcat?

Comment: whats the error given in logcat. You may be using apis from honeycomb still not available in 2.1

Comment: @balaji,,,its giving null pointer exception,,,,,,is it possible to implement tab bar in android 2.1 updated 1 and to change from 3.2 to android 2.1 ?

Comment: well you need to fix your errors. And there is tab bars in android 2.1 using activity group.

Comment: tab bar is supported from android3.0 and above

Comment: @balaji,,,means its very typical for me to make the code,,in android 2.1 updated1..actually i have to implement the full url http://www.crazysales.com.au/new-arrivals

Comment: @blessem..means it is very complex,,,, i have to make the full url in android http://www.crazysales.com.au/new-arrivals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the bellow link

https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar

It provides the Sample ActionBar(TabBar) which will run on lower versions also.

By using this code into your project only little bit modifications are enough. good luck...